# putting frames inside a table

Tags: javascript, html

Can i put two frames inside a table. I can't use an iframe. Is there any way to use frames inside a table. Please help me. The code i use is given below

```
<frameset cols="100%,0" frameBorder="no" framespacing="0" border="0">

<frame  name="leftDualPane"  scrolling="no"
        src="<%=(String)session.getAttribute("tabViewJsp")%>"
      frameborder="1" style="border-left-width: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; 
border-bottom-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px;">
  </frame>

  <frame  name="rightDualPane"  scrolling="no"
      src="<%=(String)session.getAttribute("tabViewJsp")%>"
      frameborder="7" style="border-left-width: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; 
border-bottom-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px;">
  </frame>


</frameset>
```

Comment: you can only use iframes within a table.

Comment: No, but you can use a frameset inside an iframe inside a table.

Answer (score 0):

No, frames are essentially a substitute for the body tag, see the example at the top of: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html

A solution to your problem might be to make Ajax calls and then insert the content within the cells of the table.